# Java ArrayList of Arrays, contains doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

I have an array list:

```
List<MyObj[]> list = new ArrayList<MyObj[]>();
```

I put arrays in it:

```
MyObj[] test = new MyObj[2];
test[0] = new MyObj();
test[1] = new MyObj();
list.add(test);
```

I check to see if test is contained in list:

```
if(list.contains(test)){
    System.out.println("You are smart");
}else{
    System.out.println("I are not smart");
}

>I are not smart
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is there anything between `list.add(test);` and  `if(list.contains(test)){`?

Comment: have you implement .equals method in your MyObject class ?

Comment: this is a little strange for me that you hold arrays in another array-like guy, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `equals` of `MyObj` is never called. `equals` of arrays does an identity compare.

Comment: @Arian, then how do I accomplish what I am trying to do here.

Comment: If you want a helpful answer, you have to show all relevant code. See Sam I am's comment above.

Comment: You should provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating the error.

Comment: one of the important steps of making a true [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) is to compile and run the code that you intend to post, and make sure that it demonstrates the same problem that you face.  This code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are hiding something, I cannot give a definite answer, but you can try

```
public static boolean contains(ArrayList<MyObj[]> list, MyObj[] element) {
    for (MyObj[] e: list) {
        if (Arrays.equals(e, element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of two things, you need to update your jre, or you are mutating the the array.

This works just fine:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyObj[]> list = new ArrayList<MyObj[]>();

        MyObj[] test = new MyObj[2];

        test[0] = new MyObj();
        test[1] = new MyObj();
        list.add(test);

        if(list.contains(test)){
            System.out.println("is true");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Is  not true");
        }

    }
}
class MyObj {
    public MyObj() {

    }
    public String x;

}
```

Output:

```
is true
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from the one I just removed for not being an answer?

Comment: @Heuster The one you removed was probably an excellent answer, too, if you can't see the difference.

Comment: @Heuster Pete Belford did answer the question (_either you need to update your jre, or you are mutating the the array_), and then demonstrated that that was the case by showing that the posted code does work correctly.